# Plot function with parameters from Reduce

Tags: plotting, functions

I would like to modify the question a bit. I want to plot the function `m` with different combination of `(a1,b1,a2,b2)` over a range of `d` generated also by `Reduce` below. 
How can I do that?
I don't want to manually input all combination.

```
intvars ={a1,b1,a2,b2};
m = (a2 (-1+d)-a1 d) /(b2+b1 d-b2 d);
vd =a1 + b1 m;
vdb = a2 + b2 m;
assumptions=And@@Thread[-2<= intvars <= 2] && Element[intvars,Integers] &&
 Element[d,Reals] && vd >0 && vdb<0;
comb=Reduce[assumptions];
Plot[m, (each of combination of (a1, b1,a2, b2) from comb and d range from comb]
```

Comment: `Manipulate` with `(a1,b1,a2,b2)` as parameters?

Comment: That's good. I didn't know it's possible with many parameters like that. 
One problem though. I would like to plot and see the range of the function with each combination. Because there are two many combinations 5^4 which is 625, so I can't do manually check all combination. I forgot what I have checked. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
intvars = {a1, b1, a2, b2};
m = (a2 (-1 + d) - a1 d)/(b2 + b1 d - b2 d);
vd = a1 + b1 m;
vdb = a2 + b2 m;
assumptions = 
  And @@ Thread[-2 <= intvars <= 2] && Element[intvars, Integers] && 
   Element[d, Reals] && vd > 0 && vdb < 0;
comb = Reduce[assumptions];
Plot[
 comb //
   BooleanConvert //(* convert to normal form *)
   Apply@List //(* convert sol1 || sol2 || … to {sol1, …} *)
   Map@Apply@List (*  convert each cond1 && cond 2 && … to {cond1, …} *)//
   Map[(* for each list of conditions… *)
    ConditionalExpression[(* build a ConditionalExpression *)
      m /. ToRules[And @@ Cases[#, _Equal]] (* use equalities to replace params *),
      And @@ Cases[#, Except@_Equal](* extract the inequalities *)
      ] &
    ] //
  Evaluate,
 {d, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

The key idea is to use [`BooleanConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html) to bring the solution of `Reduce` into the form `sol1 || sol2 || …`, where each of the `sol` is again `eq1 && eq2 && …`. Then we simply extract the equalities and convert them to replacement rules with [`ToRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html). The remaining inequalities are used as conditions in [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html).